# How do I return value from another table if between two times?

Tags: r, format, lookup, between

I have a dataset which looks at times for which a particular "run" occurred. This is the head() of the dataset.

```
time <- c(15:27.7, 15:27.7, 15:27.8, 15:27.9, 15:28.0)
```

I wish to return a "run number" for which if value in time is between a certain time in a dataframe it will return the corresponding run. The "lookup" table is below.

```
START   END       Run
  <fct>   <fct>   <int>
1 15:27.7 15:29.1     1
2 20:32.3 20:37.3     2
3 25:57.3 25:58.7     3
4 17:53.8 17:54.0     4
```

My desired run result should be:

```
  TIME     Run
1 15:27.7   1
2 15:27.7   1
3 15:27.8   1
4 15:27.9   1
5 15:28.0   1
```

I believe I may need to change the format of the times but not sure how to do this either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are these all Minutes:Seconds?

Comment: These are Minutes, Seconds and Milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you'll have to convert all of your "times", which look like factors in your lookup table, into date/time or "POSIXct" class objects so that you can then lookup the values. The `as.POSIXct` function can do this for you.

```
df$time2 <- as.POSIXct(df$time, format="%M:%OS")
lkup$START <- as.POSIXct(lkup$START, format="%M:%OS")
lkup$END <- as.POSIXct(lkup$END, format="%M:%OS")
```

Then use one of many methods to lookup the Run value from the lookup table based on the time value in your main data frame. Here I'll use data table's non-equi join as it's fairly simple.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(lkup)[setDT(df), on=.(START<=time2, END>=time2), .(id, time, Run)]
   id    time Run
1:  1 15:27.7   1
2:  2 15:29.1   1
3:  3 20:32.3   2
4:  4 25:58.7   3
5:  5 17:53.9   4
```

---

**Data**:

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:5, time = c("15:27.7", "15:29.1", "20:32.3", 
"25:58.7", "17:53.9")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

  id    time
1  1 15:27.7
2  2 15:29.1
3  3 20:32.3
4  4 25:58.7
5  5 17:53.9 

lkup <- structure(list(START = c("15:27.7", "20:32.3", "25:57.3", "17:53.8"
), END = c("15:29.1", "20:37.3", "25:58.7", "17:54.0"), Run = 1:4), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))

    START     END Run
1 15:27.7 15:29.1   1
2 20:32.3 20:37.3   2
3 25:57.3 25:58.7   3
4 17:53.8 17:54.0   4
```